# How to access JSON Blob contents in python in Azure function App

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions

I am using HTTP trigger in Azure function app.I want to do some data transformation on JSON data which is stored in Blob storage.
I am no able to extract JSON file data in function.

Can anyone tell me how to access JSON file in function?
End to end flow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, You can access a file in blob storage by passing the filename in the HTTP API call and making changes in the function.json file. Below is the code that worked for me.

### **init**.py

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: func.InputStream):
    input_file = inputblob.read()

    print("JSON Body",input_file)

    return func.HttpResponse(input_file)
```

### local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "storageacc_STORAGE": "<Connection_String>"
  }
}
```

### function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction":"in",
      "name": "inputblob",
      "path": "upload/{filename}",
      "connection": "storageacc_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]